# Image not displaying using cordova-plugin-local-notifications attachment property

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-notifications

I am new with `Cordova` android development and looking to create a very simple app to show what is the latest movies and show the banner of the movie to users my code is below, the notification is showing but it's not displaying the banner. my image is saved inside the `www/img` folder

```
 cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
                id: 1,
                title: 'My first notification',
                text: 'Thats pretty easy...',
                attachments: ['file://img/logo.png'],
                foreground: true,
                vibrate: true
            });
```

Here is my file path

[image]

Below is an example of what I want to achieve, any suggestion would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your push notification look like and take a look of the name of the file and its extension, not that the file is named Logo.jpg and you write logo.jpg. Android is linuxbased and this can cause errors.

my try to build it with your code, the pure push is without image, after clicking pull it from above, it will show the image like that: 
[image]

My Code is a simple one in index.js:

```
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
// 'pause', 'resume', etc.
onDeviceReady: function() {
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        id: 1,
        title: 'My first notification',
        text: 'Thats pretty easy...',
        attachments: ['file://img/logo.png'],
        foreground: true,
        vibrate: true
    });

}
```

The Push Message out of the App
[image: Push out of the App]

Look at this Gif to see the image (i know, the quality is horrible):
[image: Look at this]

Comment: Hello!, I updated my question showing the file path.

Comment: i tested the code on my own, the first look of the push message ist minimized, if you look at it the image is shown.

Comment: Can you update your answer and show me your complete code i want to cross compare

Comment: If you have any questions about it, i´m here for you :)

Comment: Still, my attachments are not showing maybe because of my android version this really puzzles me I will try on a different android phone.

Comment: One thing is left that i want to say, the push is on show without image, you have to push the topbar down to see an image as you want. I add a gif to the Answer for you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, is there a way to change the height of the notification?

Comment: Sorry, i don´t know that. You should ask the author of that plugin if that is possible.